# AngularJS passing HTML to scope

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Where I want the html to go:

```
<div>{{display}}</div>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
     $scope.contact = //get the html from contact.html
     $scope.display = $scope.contact
});
```

contact.html

```
<form>
  ...
</form>
```

How could I pass the html to the js file?

UPDATE:  I can't use ng-include because this is a SPA, so the area where the contact.html will go isn't static.

Comment: create an angular service which provides your contact html data

Comment: I don't know how to do this, I'm new to angularJS. I have seen people mention services, but I do not know how to use them

Comment: Can't you simply use [ngInclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)?

Comment: No, the area where this contact form is changes, building a SPA. So I can't use the ng-include

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the [`$sce`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) service and [`ng-sanitize`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize). Once you have the HTML you want to include in your controller/directive, use :

```
$sce.trustAsHtml($scope.htmlItem);
```

And in your view:

```
<div ng-bind-html="htmlItem"></div>
```

And the HTML will be rendered onto the page.

Comment: This is something I was looking for, but how would I get the contact.html into the $scope?

Comment: make request :D

forgot, how it in angular, but something like this (it's bad practice for angular, use angular http service):
$.ajax({url: '/contact.html', success: function(data){ $scope.display = data; $scope.$apply(); }})

Comment: How long is the content you are wanting to toggle around and under what conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Alternativelly, you can you ng-include.

```
    <!-- HEADER -->
    <div ng-include="'partials/header.html'"> </div>

    <!-- MAIN VIEW -->
    <div animated-view></div> //This is using ngRoute to populate content.

    <!-- FOOTER -->
    <div ng-include="'partials/footer.html'"> </div>
```

Remember to use nested " ' ' " for Angular to understand.

You should also take a look at [$RouteProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider).

This is a [example of mine](https://github.com/Rodmentou/InfinityRPG/blob/master/public/app.js), showing how to use RouteProvider to populate ng-view. You can set the view, controllers and initial variables on the routeProvider.

Comment: I can't use this because the data on the page isn't static, it will change when the user interacts with the page

Comment: Edited my answer. Look at my example code. The views/partials aren't static and don't need to be. [This page](https://github.com/Rodmentou/InfinityRPG/blob/master/public/partials/game.html), for example, shows exactly that.

Comment: @DanielMcCrevan Take a look at [$routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider), I think that this is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I see what you are doing here, but I don't think this is what I need. I just need a simple way to get the HTML into a $scope variable, would it be fine for me to just put the HTML as a string in a variable?

Comment: When I was beginning with Angular, I did used plain strings in scope variables but I don't remember how to apply then. Let me test a sec.